# Hypothesis testing of two Poisson distributions

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, hypothesis-testing

[image]

Hi guys I have been tackling a number of statistics questions in prep for a test and am unsure on the second part of this question.

I can solve a easily with the combined likelihood being $ce^{-(n+m)\alpha-m\tau}\alpha^{n\bar{x}}(\alpha+\tau)^{m\bar{y}}$ with $c$ as a constant.

However now I am unsure how to solve the rest of part b. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please [do not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: For part (i), under the null hypothesis, $\tau=0.$ Now the combined likelihood you've written is a function of $\alpha,$ so you can maximize it (the best way is probably by taking a log, then taking a derivative and setting equal to zero, and then checking this is a maximizer).

Comment: ok thanks ive done that and got $\frac{n\bar{x} + m\bar{y}}{n+m}$ any idea where to go from here?